# Asymptotic notation Big $\mathcal{O}$ How to understand absolute value in an expression

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

$|2\mathcal{O}(f(n))-\mathcal{O}(f(n))+d|=\mathcal{O}(f(n)). d>0 $ constant and $f(n)>1$.

I know how to prove such claims ,but when an absolute value appears I do not understand how to relate to it, I tried to divide it into two cases
but It was hard and now I'm not sure that It can be proven.

how i can understand that?
Is it possible to prove it at all?

Comment: My guess of what it means:  if $\alpha(n) = O(f(n))$ and $\beta(n) = O(f(n))$, then $|2\alpha(n)-\beta(n)+d|=O(f(n))$.  Each of those three statements is something about a $\limsup$.  So, yes, it is possible to prove, using inequalities and arguing with $\limsup$.

Answer (score 1):

> The equation
>   \begin{align*}
> |2\mathcal{O}(f(n))-\mathcal{O}(f(n))+d|=\mathcal{O}(f(n))\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>   means that $S_1\subseteq S_2$,

- where $S_1$ is the set of all functions of the form
  \begin{align*}
  |2 g_1(n)-g_2(n)+d|
  \end{align*}
  such that there exists constants $C_1,C_2>0$ with
  \begin{align*}
  &|g_1(n)|<C_1 |f(n)|\qquad\qquad \forall n\in\mathbb{N}\\
  &|g_2(n)|<C_2|f(n)|\qquad\qquad \forall n\in\mathbb{N}
  \end{align*}
- and where $S_2$ is the set of all functions $$g_3(n)$$ such that there is a constant $C_3>0$ with
  \begin{align*}
  |g_3(n)|<C_3|f(n)|\qquad\qquad \forall n\in\mathbb{N}
  \end{align*}

> We obtain from the inequalities above
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{|2 g_1(n)-g_2(n)+d|}&\leq2|g_1(n)|+|g_2(n)|+d\\
> &\color{blue}{<} 2C_1 f(n)+C_2 f(n)+d f(n)\tag{2}\\
> &=\color{blue}{\left(2C_1+C_2+d\right) f(n)}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
>
> In (2) we also use the assumption $f(n)>1$ to get $d< d f(n)$.
>
> **Conclusion:** From (3) we conclude with $C_3=2C_1+C_2+d$ that whenever a function is in $S_1$ it is also in $S_2$ and the claim (1) follows.

*Hint:* Note that we are dealing in (1) with *one way* equalities. The right  side of the  equation does not give more information than the left side, and it may give less. The right side is a *crudification* of the right side.

A thorough introduction and  also a reasoning for the $=$ - notation (namely tradition (three times) and the natural  approach) is  presented in chapter *Asymptotics*  in *[Concrete Mathematics](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)* by R.L. Graham, D.E. Knuth and O. Patashnik.

Comment: First of all, thank you. secondly, what about the inclusion on the other side? (S2 inclusion in S1 )

Comment: @Arthur_AdinayevProj: You're welcome. I've added a hint which might be useful.